# Why cyclical learning rate has faster training time?

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent

In [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01186), Leslie implements an oscillating learning rate that when I train for 5 epochs using cyclical learning rate is faster than usual static learning rate for the same 5 epochs, why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The referred paper seems to answer your question, as it is the paper (as far as I know) that suggested using cyclical learning rate. Among other things, they say

> The essence of this learning rate policy comes from the observation
>   that increasing the learning rate might have a short term negative
>   effect and yet achieve a longer term beneficial effect. This
>   observation leads to the idea of letting the learning rate vary within
>   a range of values rather than adopting a stepwise fixed or
>   exponentially decreasing value.

So, as with many things in deep learning, they observed that it works. Everything beyond that would be post-hoc rationalizations why it could work. The paper does not describe any deeper theoretical background behind it, because there is none. It just works.

What the paper shows, is that when training the neural networks with cyclical learning rate, they *converge faster*, i.e. they need *less epochs, or iterations*, to achieve point where their performance does not really improve any further with more iterations. The paper *does not* claim that the time per iteration decreased.

**Given your comment,** you seem to be referring to [this DataCamp tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/cyclical-learning-neural-nets), where the author claims that cyclical learning rate makes the code run faster (in terms of time, not epochs). First of all, this is a nonsense. The learning rate schedulers adjust learning rate before, or after each epoch, or step (doesn't matter that much, it is about implementation), so the additional few lines of code are run *independently* of the actual code. It is *impossible* that running few more lines of code could make the overall code run faster, it should run slightly slower (by negligible amount of time in this case). To prove the claim, the author uses code example *with a bug*, where he use different batch sizes (by 10x) for both conditions, what obviously has an impact on the run time.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear, it does not converge faster, it does N multiplications faster when oscillating the learning rate. w = lr_usual x Dw should take the same time that w = lr_oscillating x Dw, but not, the oscillating takes less time.

Comment: @JaderMartins I don't know if I understand you. You mean less epochs since conference? Or less time per epoch? If the latter, I don't know how you estimated it, if so, it is a coincidence, since it is an extra simple arthmetic operation, so it should not change anything.

Comment: The latter, see here for example https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/cyclical-learning-neural-nets, regular learning rate for 10 epochs took 87 seconds and cyclic took 44 seconds for 10 epochs.

Comment: @JaderMartins they used 10x smaller batch size between two cars so the comparison does not show anything. The fact that they use timeit shows that the author does not understand what they are saying. The advantage is that you need less epochs, not that magically few lines of code would make the other multiline code run faster...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've reproduced a controlled experiment and confirmed that there's not significant difference. This link was the first that was "confirming" my claim, but the motivation for this claim was a dialog with a coworker and by (biased) experience with this learning schedule.

Comment: If someone stumbles upon this question while looking for a theoretical explanation of why it works, according to this 2021 review of non-convex optimization https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.06188, scientists basically have no idea